# Dynamically give Id to button, Commandargument send value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Here is my part of Shop.aspx code:

```
        <% foreach(var item in items){ %>
           ...
           <asp:Button id="btnBuy" runat="server" class="btn" Text="Buy" OnClick ="btnBuy_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("item.id") %>' />
        <% } %>
```

I've got a loop where I create few buttons to my shopping items, and I need them to have id of my item

```
protected void btnBuy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int itemId = Convert.ToInt32(btnBuy.CommandArgument);
     }
```

On click i need to have id of the item/button clicked, to save them later in my database.

Problem -

When i click on button btnbuy.CommandArgument is "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong: you wrote c#in asp style. You have to use a `Repeater` and then you can manage `ItemCommand` for every button click.

**Aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="myRepeater_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label id="myLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Item)(Container.DataItem)).ProductName %>'/>
   <asp:Button id="btnBuy" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Buy" CommandName="Click" CommandArgument='<%# ((Item)(Container.DataItem)).ProductId %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**c#** (eg. OnLoad)

```
List<Item> myCollection = ...; // get list of items
myRepeater.DataSource = myCollection;
myRepeater.DataBind();
```

...

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemCommand(Object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
{
      if(e.CommandName == "Click")
      {
          int idRecord = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
          // do something using idRecord or
          // get sender properties: ((Button)e.CommandSource).Text
      }
}
```

Comment: It looks fine, but i've got  problem, co i have a list: List<Items> items, and Items is my class with parameters (id, name, category, ..etc) and how can I put it into this code?

Comment: i've got an error "The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found "

Comment: Item is your class "Items". Class would be singular noun

Comment: yeah i know that I wrote that and still get that error

Comment: Maybe you miss include in aspx? Try Full Namespace in aspx.

Comment: sorry but how include in aspx?

Comment: YourNamespace.Items instead of Item

Comment: tried this too, and nothing :/ thanks for help but i think i will do this diffrent way!

Comment: Can you edit your first post with the updated version of code?

Comment: I did it different way, i change this repeater into place holder, and in my aspx.cs code i have ma loop and add dynamically tools and ids. And I think its much easier. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Using repeater you can write code in aspx, using placeholder you must write con in cs. According to me repeater is better if you have to change somthing.